# Getting Cakephp to work on a Debian server, but I'm having a missing controller error at the root

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, debian

I've been trying to get a cakePHP app to run on a Debian Server. It works find on localhost, using WAMP. At first I had issues with the rewrite not working. So I attempted to fix that by changing the owner of some of the folders to `www-data`, from root, as I read in other places on the internet that that would help. I changed the root of the cakephp app to www-data, and everything under that to `www-data` (recursively). But this still did not fix it.

So I went to instructions for if you can't get url rewriting working, by doing the following...

So I found some other instructions that said to get rid of the `./htaccess`, `/app/.htaccess` and `/app/webroot/.htaccess` files, which I did.

And I uncommented the following lines in my cakephp folder:

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', 'img/');
Configure::write('App.cssBaseUrl', 'css/');
Configure::write('App.jsBaseUrl', 'js/');
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Missing Controller
Error: CakeController could not be found.
Error: Create the class CakeController below in file: app/Controller/CakeController.php
<?php
```

class CakeController extends AppController {

}

```
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
Stack Trace
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
ROOT/index.php line 41 → require(string)
```

I think I have to change the `App.baseUrl` or the `App.fullBaseUrl`, to something else, but I am not sure to what.

The root of the application is in `/ <root>/home/webdev/webroot/Cake`, and the public domain is located in `/ <root>/home/webdev/webroot`. I think that info may be relevant to solving the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be lacking basic knowledge of setting up the server which leads me to think that you might have mixed up lots of different "workarounds" in your way of trying to make it work, such that it might be too difficult to fix it now through this.

If you have root access to the debian server I assume you're talking about a VPS you own. Then you most probably can reset it to a fresh install and start over.

So first things first:

- You're developing on windows and will be serving your app on unix (linux). Beware windows is case insensitive and unix is not, if you don't follow conventions you'll definitely end up with this issue at some point (i.e. `webroot/Cake` or `webroot/cake` are the same thing to windows but different on unix).
- By default you can't have Apache serve files from from user home folders (`/home/user/...`) but from `/var/www`. If you want it the first way you need to set it up properly, which would mean to know how to create an apache site config file and/or messing with apache's main config file. I would leave that for later if I were you.
- The folder/files in any folder that Apache must serve need to be accessible/readable by www-data user or group. Exception is the application's `tmp` folder that need to also be writable by the same user or group. If you put them on `/var/www/app` you can `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/app -R`which will save you lots of time in your way to make things work at first.
- By default Apache doesn't come with rewrite enabled. You need to `a2enable rewrite && service apache2 restart`. You will also need to check the directive AllowOverride" in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` under directory `/var/www/` to make sure it is set to `AllowOverride All`. If not amend and restart apache.

If you apply the above you should be able to properly access your app under `http://server_name/app` and follow on from there.